# How to use scss with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have added following gem to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem "sass-rails", "~> 4.0.0"
```

I have a `main.css` in my `app/assetsstylesheets/`, and had just single style defined:

```
.container {
  height:500px;
}
```

I just renamed `main.css` to `main.css.scss` and modified the file to:

```
.container 
  height: 500px
```

It seems that file is not being parsed appropriately. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem here? Here is the error:

```
Invalid CSS after "  height:": expected pseudoclass or pseudoelement, was " 500"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells that `"  height:"` is parsed as part of the selector, and is expecting more because you do not have `{`. That means sass is parsing it as SCSS, not SASS. To have it parsed as SASS, write in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
config.sass.syntax = :sass
```

Comment: While this will work, it will make SCSS parsing completely unavailable. sass-rails already supports both formats simultaneously by using the correct file extension.

Comment: @colinm The OP is not using the correct file extension. This is the only way I can think of to overcome that.

Answer (score 1):

You were writing SCSS syntax but not SASS. SASS has new syntax just like CSS.

> The original syntax, called "the indented syntax" uses a syntax similar to Haml.[3] It uses indentation to separate code blocks and newline characters to separate rules. The newer syntax, "SCSS", uses block formatting like that of CSS. It uses braces to denote code blocks and semicolons to separate lines within a block. The indented syntax and SCSS files are traditionally given the extensions .sass and .scss respectively. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language)

This is typical SASS style

```
$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

http://sass-lang.com/guide

Answer (score 1):

You're using Sass syntax in an SCSS file. sass-rails determines which parser to use from the file extension.

Sass goes in `.sass` files; SCSS goes in `.scss` files.